# Can the browser open new tab and switch to that tab in one action?

Tags: browser

When I browse the web I want to be able to open a new tab and switch to that tab e.g. ctrl+click and ctrl+tab in one action. Is there such a function in any browser? Or can I script it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a solution that will work for every browser, but some (most?) of them support `Ctrl+Shift+Click`.

Comment: Works in chrome and Internet Explorer

Comment: Should also work in Opera and Firefox. AFAIR older versions of Internet Explorer tended to open a new window instead of a tab, but Edge is behaving as expected.